# Accessing results of gregexpr

Tags: r

I would like to use the gregexpr function to find the start and finish positions of substrings within a string. The function works fine in the console, but I cannot access the results for either the start positions or string lengths:

```
g <- gregexpr("e", "cheese")

g

[[1]]
[1] 3 4 6
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"index.type")
[1] "chars"
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

`g[[1]][1]` merely brings up the first value (3), but I need to create a vector with ALL values for both start positions and length. Thanks.

Comment: You are getting only the first element of the first list element. Do this: `g[[1]]`

Comment: This just brings up the entire content of g. I need to be able access individual elements, e.g. 3, 4, 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract them in this way :

```
g <- gregexpr("e", "cheese")

# one liner for : starts <- g[[1]]
#                 attributes(starts) <- NULL
starts <- `attributes<-`(g[[1]],NULL) 

lens <- attr(g[[1]],'match.length')

> starts
[1] 3 4 6
> lens
[1] 1 1 1
```

Of course this works only if text is of length 1 (as in the example, since it contains only `"cheese"`). Otherwise you'll need to iterate over the elements of `g` using `g[[2]]`, `g[[3]]` ... etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use unlist and you will receive list of position. Once need to have only first and last, min and max can be used

```
unlist(g)
```

[1] 3 4 6

Comment: Brill. Very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be:

```
g <- gregexpr("e", "cheese")

g[[1]][1:length(g[[1]])]
#[1] 3 4 6
```

And the microbenchmarking with the `unlist` approach:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   g[[1]][1:length(g[[1]])], 
   unlist(g)
)

#Unit: nanoseconds
#                     expr min  lq   mean median  uq   max neval
# g[[1]][1:length(g[[1]])] 378 378 653.80    379 756  8307   100
#                unlist(g)   0 378 544.32    378 378 15104   100
```